# Oracle SQL ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error in CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case-statement

I'm executing a query with the following CASE statement in the select clause:

```
select (case instr(listagg(D.first_name, ',') 
    within group (order by D.first_name), ',')
when 0 
then substr(listagg(D.first_name, ',') 
    within group (order by D.first_name), 1)
else substr(listagg(D.first_name, ',') 
    within group (order by D.first_name), 1, instr(listagg(D.first_name, ',') 
    within group (order by D.first_name), ',') - 1) end) Advisor1FName
from ....
```

SQL Developer throws an ORA-00907 missing right paranthesis error.

What is going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks OK. you can try to replace all of it with * and try again to be sure that substract that we see has a problem

Comment: Maybe an `end` is missing at the end of `case`

Comment: @Jens Sorry, the 'end' keyword may have disappeared while copying. The 'end' does exist in the query, and the same problem exists.

Comment: I'm rolling back your edit. Adding "Solved" and the solution to your question isn't how StackOverflow works (it's a "question and answer" site, which means a question gets posted and then it gets answered, in the space marked "Your Answer"). If you want to post the solution for future readers, you can [post a self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer); you can even accept it yourself as the correct one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by enclosing the entire listagg function in brackets. It's strange that they were required, but that's what solved the problem.

So,

```
substr(listagg(D.first_name, ',') 
    within group (order by D.first_name), 1)
```

becomes

```
substr((listagg(D.first_name, ',') 
    within group (order by D.first_name)), 1)
```